# Suitable words or phrasal verbs

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-usage

Consider this situation: A girl has been lost and her parents are trying to find her. Hence, can I describe this circumstance as the following:

- The child, who has been **lost from** her parents, is crying as she is watching thousands of strange people passing by.

Is the bold phrase accurate? If not, what is the best substitute for it? Thanks for any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is a tiny one.

The child, who has been ***lost by*** her parents, is crying as she is watching thousands of strange people passing by.

I would go further with:

The child, who has been ***lost by*** her parents, is crying as she ***watches*** thousands of strange people passing by.

Less is more with:

The child, ***lost by*** her parents, is crying as she ***watches*** thousands of strangers passing by.

Answer (score 4):

You don't become *lost from someone/something*, but rather *someone loses you*. A more natural way to write this sentence is:

> "The child, who has been lost by her parents, is crying as she watches thousands of strange people pass by."

Or we can use the phrase ***separated from***.

> "The child, who has been separated from her parents, is crying as she watches thousands of strange people pass by."

Answer (score 3):

As @V0ight points already out losing someone is more the by than the from way. Mostly kids are lost for a few reasons. You can try to specify it a bit more clearly.

Maybe *the kid has **[wandered away from](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wander)** her parents*, or maybe *the kid has simply **been forgotten by** her parents.*

You can however stay with **lost** and the kid's perspective, if you write *The kid, who **[has lost sight of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sight?q=lost+sight#sight__39)** her parents, ...*

> **lose sight of**
>
> Be no longer able to see:
>
> when night fell, the crew lost sight of the strange monster

-[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sight?q=lost+sight#sight__39)

It's really about what you want to focus on.

Answer (score -2):

I would like to rephrase it as below please.
The child, who has been ***set apart*** from her parents, is crying as she is watching thousands of strange people passing by.

: set apart from others
Synonyms:
isolate, keep apart, sequester, sequestrate
Type of:
disunite, divide, part, separate
force, take, or pull apart.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/set%20apart

Hope it helps. Welcome.

Comment: -1 "set apart" sounds as if it has been done **intentionally* - which is clearly not what "lost" means.

Comment: that phrase doesn't work here because to *set apart* something is to lay it aside for future use, and is used for inanimate objects. For example, you would *set apart* a piece of paper after writing it. When it's used in the context of humans, it denotes a person being noted for a quality that others don't share: for example an Olympian is *set apart* from other professional athletes in that the former is even more skilled and is the best in his field.

Comment: Let me have a look please.

Answer (score -2):

We may say as follows
The child, who has been ***separated or disjointed*** from her parents, is crying as she is watching thousands of strange people passing by.

"disjointed
star
see definition of disjointed 
show
    adj loose, disconnected"
and

Separate, verb (used without object), separated, separating.
8.
to part company; withdraw from personal association (often followed by from):

### to separate from a church.

Please see
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disjoint?s=t
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/separate

Comment: 'separated' is a good choice. But you cannot use "disjointed" in this context. You cannot just browse for a synonym and assume that you can use in instead of the source word,  If you do not know the answer, please do not just try to make one up.  And what's the relevance of "to separate from a church"? Why is it in large bold by itself?